# HTML5 embedded videos not working after upgrade to 19.04

Tags: firefox, video, chromium, ffmpeg

[image]

I am not really sure what is going on. I am doing some web development, and when I embed any videos or go to a "browser supported video type tester" site this is all  I get. I didnt have this issue before. Videos on like youtube work. I made sure that the extended codecs and ffmpeg for chromium are installed and still nothing. I tried on firefox and I just get an error message of:

```
No video with supported format and MIME type found.
```

I've tried embedding with .ogg, .mp4 and WebM and I get the same error message. Not really sure what else to do here.

I tried the exact same code on my Windows computer in the same browsers at work and it worked just fine, so I definitely believe it is a Ubuntu issue. Not sure what to do.